# Script in a loaded html with ajax doesn't run

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a major problem here and I'm running out of options. I hope someone can help me.

I have a link (script Number 1) that loads a html file (single-project.html) in a div after it is clicked. I'm using jQuery (script Number 2).

**But the script number 3, that is in the single-project.html doesn't run.**

Here a picture for more clearness

> [image]

**Here the script Number 3, which must fill the div with the id rex**

```
$('#rex').ready(function() {
    var url="genredetail.php";
    var activitydetail = sessionStorage.activitydetail;

    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        $.each(json.genredetail,function(i,item){
            if(item.name == activitydetail){
                $('<p class="excerpt">' + item.beschreibung3 + '</p>').appendTo('#rex');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

script Number 2

```
$('#betriebe').on('click', '.ajax-portfolio', function() {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.close-ajaxWrapper').css("background-color","white");
        $('.close-ajax img').tooltip();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#div1').offset().top - 100)},'slow', function(){
            $('#div1').load(url + ' #transmitter', function (){
                $('.gallery').slideDown("slow");});
            $('a.close-ajax').click(function(){
                $('.close-ajax img').tooltip('hide')
                $('.close-ajaxWrapper').css("background-color","transparent");
                $('div#filters').slideDown(1000, function(){
                    $('div#div1').empty();
                });
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#div1').offset().top - 0)});

                return false;
            });//End: click()
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: Show us script nr. 2

Comment: `$.ready` only works on Document level, not on Element level: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Spokey no script number 2 is in a external js file!

Comment: Oh, meant script number 3. If it's in the head it might get removed by jQuery

Comment: I see you are loading a document fragment (`load(url + ' #transmitter' ...`) are you sure script number 3 is in that fragment?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ read the paragraph about page fragments

Comment: first i tried to implement in the single-project.html.
then in the page. script number 3 isn't in script number 2. i don't know how connect this 2 scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$.load` to insert a document fragment. By design, this will NOT execute javascript. You can read the documentation about loading Page Fragments and Script Execution in the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Either, you include the contents of script 3 to be within the `$.load` callback of script 2, or you put script 3 in a seperate file and execute it with [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), right after you have loaded the HTML fragment.

I think the first option is conceptually simpler to understand so you should try this:

```
$('#betriebe').on('click', '.ajax-portfolio', function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $('.close-ajaxWrapper').css("background-color","white");
  $('.close-ajax img').tooltip();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#div1').offset().top - 100)},'slow', function(){
    $('#div1').load(url + ' #transmitter', function (){

      // this gets executed as soon as the document fragment
      // has been loaded and inserted
      $('.gallery').slideDown("slow");

      var url="genredetail.php";
      var activitydetail = sessionStorage.activitydetail;

      $.getJSON(url, function(json){
        $.each(json.genredetail, function(i,item){
          if (item.name == activitydetail){
            $('<p class="excerpt">' + item.beschreibung3 + '</p>').appendTo('#rex');
          }
        }); // end $.each
      }); // end $.getJSON
    }); // end $.load

    $('a.close-ajax').click(function(){
      $('.close-ajax img').tooltip('hide')
      $('.close-ajaxWrapper').css("background-color","transparent");
      $('div#filters').slideDown(1000, function(){
        $('div#div1').empty();
      });
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#div1').offset().top - 0)});

      return false;
    }); // end: click a.close-ajax
  }); // end: animate

  return false;

});// end: click .ajax-portfolio
```

Comment: with my bad english is this a tortur. but thanks. i will try :-)

Comment: could you give me the full solution for money?

Comment: this is not the place for job negotiations. I can give you more hints if you need, though.

Comment: i tried do insert the function after $('#div1').load(url + ' #transmitter', function (){
                $('.gallery').slideDown("slow");
but the problem is still there.

Comment: you mean you have tried the code from my updated answer? what does not work? does the documen fragment get pulled in? but your data not? have you had a look at the 'network' section of your browsers debugger? (firefox: ctrl+shift+i, chrome: F12) Does it load the fragment and the data?

Comment: ok i saw the network section in mozilla firefox. the page single-project and the genredetail.php has been loaded. this 2 files appears in the debugger from Mozilla firefox. with the status "200 OK".
Is this possible that i don't find the solution :-(

Comment: OH now the code run correctly. THANK YOU SO MUCH! You are my hero!!!! Thanks thanks and Thanks!

Comment: can i ask you one more time? why is the script running the single-project.html and the genre detail.php 2 times? i get my output twice :-S

Comment: cant think of a reason off the top of my head. put it in a new question and maybe somebody else will have an idea

Answer (score 0):

Your script is loaded before the element is created so probably you could try 
$('document').find('#rex') and chain next function to do what you have to do